# continue statement in a do while loop

Tags: c, while-loop, continue

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
enum {false, true}; 
    
int main() 
{ 
   int i = 1; 
   do
   { 
      printf("%d\n", i); 
      i++; 
      if (i < 15) 
        continue; 
   } while (false); 
      
   getchar(); 
   return 0; 
}
```

What happens after the `continue` statement is executed in this code?

Where does the control go?

Comment: @FredLarson The `continue` will be executed because `2 < 15` is true.

Comment: That (valid) construct is easily checkable by executing the program.

Comment: If you want to use `false` and `true` (and `bool`), you can [`#include <stdbool.h>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/boolean).

Comment: @MikeCAT, I think he said **after** the `continue`. Meaning does it go back to the top of the loop, or does it go to the while condition.

Answer (score 11):

The next statement will be `while (false);` which ends the `do-while` loop so after that it executes `getchar();`

In general:

```
do
{
    ...
    statements
    ...

    continue;   // Act as "GOTO continue_label"

    ...
    statements
    ...

continue_label:
} while (...);
```

If you want to try it out, you can use this code:

```
int i = 0;
do
{
    printf("After do\n");
    ++i;
    if (i < 2) 
    {
        printf("Before continue\n");
        continue;
    }
    printf("Before while\n");
} while(printf("Inside while\n") && i < 2);
```

Output + comments to explain:

```
After do              // Start first loop
Before continue       // Execute continue, consequently "Before while" is not printed
Inside while          // Execute while
After do              // Start second loop
Before while          // Just before the while (i.e. continue not called in this loop)
Inside while          // Execute while
```

Comment: What would be the recommended way if you want something similar to `continue` to unconditionally go back up to the **top** of the loop? Do I have to use a `goto`?

Comment: @QwertYuiop There is no C statement to make the execution "go back" to `do`.  So `goto` will be needed. That said, it's probably better to reconsider your loop design so that a goto isn't needed

Answer (score 5):

> ISO/IEC 9899:2011, 6.8.6.2 The continue statement
>
> [...]
>
> (2) A `continue` statement causes a jump to the loop-continuation
> portion of the smallest enclosing iteration statement; that is, to the
> end of the loop body. More precisely, in each of the statements
>
> ```
> while (/* ... */) {
> /* ... */
> continue;
> /* ... */
> contin: ;
> }
>
> do {
> /* ... */
> continue;
> /* ... */
> contin: ;
> } while (/* ... */);
>
> for (/* ... */) {
> /* ... */
> continue;
> /* ... */
> contin: ;
> }
> ```
>
> [...] it is equivalent to `goto contin;`

**What happens after continue statement is executed in this code? Where does the control go?**

To the end of the loop, i.e. `while ( false )` in your code, which will exit the loop.

Answer (score 3):

From [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/continue-statement-c?view=vs-2019):

> The continue statement passes control to the next iteration of the
> *nearest enclosing* `do`, `for`, *or* `while` *statement* in which it appears,
> bypassing any remaining statements in the `do`, `for`, or `while` statement
> body

Because the closest one of these is the `while(false)` statement, execution flow continues to that statement, and exits the loop.

This would be true even if there were other statements between the `continue` and `while(false)`  For example:

```
int main() 
{ 
   int i = 1; 
   do
   { 
      printf("%d\n", i); 
      i++; 
      if (i < 15) 
        continue;          // forces execution flow to while(false)
      printf("i >= 15\n"); // will never be executed
   } while (false); 
   ...
```

The `continue;` statement here means the `printf` statement following it will never be executed because execution flow continues to the nearest one of the loop constructs.  Again, in this case `while(false)`.

Answer (score 1):

When you use **continue** statement, further statements inside the loop get skipped and control goes to next iteration which is "condition check" in your case (in case of for loop, it goes to the third statement of for loop where increment/decrement is done to a variable generally). Since the condition is "false", iteration stops.